# Consume REST API's from SilverLight application

Tags: rest, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I consume REST services in a SilverLight application that do not have a Cross-domain Policy File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't if the web service and Silverlight applications are on different domains.

See this link for more information

http://www.devtoolshed.com/explanation-cross-domain-and-client-access-policy-files-silverlight